# Multisite pagination issue by multi query archive 404

Tags: wp-query, pagination, query

Im using https://github.com/miguelpeixe/WP_Query_Multisite to collect posts to the mainsite from others. My archive page is

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$rows_cnt = 0;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
);

if(get_current_blog_id() == 1) {
    $args['multisite'] = 1;
    $args['sites__in'] = array( 1, 2, 3, 5, 6);
}


$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
    if($rows_cnt == 0) {
?>
                    <div class="row">
<?
    }
    $rows_cnt++;
?>  

                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 newsBlock">
                            <? the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                            <p><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>"><?the_title(); ?></a></p>
                            <time><? the_time('j F Y'); ?></time>
                        </div>
<?  if($rows_cnt == 4) { ?>
                        </div>
    <?  
        $rows_cnt = 0;
    }
    ?>              
     <?php endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
     if (function_exists("pagination")) {
        pagination($query->max_num_pages);
    } ?>
```

Paginate by that custom function http://sgwordpress.com/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/

And the issue is - for example i have 3 posts on the mainsite, and 1+1+1 on the subsites and 1 post per page. `$query->max_num_pages` return correct number of all posts (3+1+1+1 = 6) and im getting correct pagination with 6 pages, but surfing after 3rd page (number of posts at the mainsite) im getting 404. I think it happends because WP 'thinking' that i have only 3 paginations, because he stored 3 posts and 1 per page (mainsite).

I can not figure out how to solve it, can somebody help me?